# How do we define the Hermitian adjoint of $u$ in the case where the domain and codomain of $u$ differ?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_of_a_linear_map#Relation_to_the_Hermitian_adjoint):

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces and $u : X \rightarrow Y$ is a
>   linear map, then the transpose of $u$... and the Hermitian adjoint of
>   $u$... are related.

I don't get this. In particular, how do we define the Hermitian adjoint of $u$ in the case where the domain and codomain of $u$ differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjoint is a map $u^* : Y \rightarrow X$ such that

$$\langle ux, y\rangle_Y = \langle x, u^*y\rangle_X$$

for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

Comment: Is it possible to give a more explicit description of $u^*$? In particular, if I know $u$, how do I compute $u^*y$?

Comment: @goblin In general the argument goes like this: for a fixed $y \in Y$ we have a continuous linear functional on $X$ defined by $x \mapsto \langle ux, y \rangle_Y$.  By the Hilbert space Riesz representation theorem any such functional is of the form $x \mapsto \langle x, z \rangle_X$ for some $z \in X$.  This $z$ is what we define $u^* y$ to be.